# Minimize or collapse a bootstrap 2.3.2 modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Are there a way to add a minimize feature to bootstrap modal dialogs?

```
 <div class="modal hide fade modal-admin" id="testModal" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <a data-dismiss="modal" class="close">×</a>
          <h3 id='dialog-heading'></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="dialog-data"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" >Close</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveChanges">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using it like a static draggable dialog:

```
   $('#testModal').modal({backdrop:false})
   $('#testModal').draggable({handle: ".modal-header"});
```

Maybe I'm using a wrong widget for that, but what else?

By minimize I mean that, minimize or collapse the dialog like a little
window widget.

Jquery-ui dialogs have a feature like that: http://jsbin.com/ehagoy/154

Why a -1?

Comment: What does "minimize" mean with respect to a modal? By definition, modals disallow action outside themselves.

Comment: Define minimize. Right now, you can close it and reopen it...

Comment: A better approach might be to change what's available to trigger the modal--add a tab to the side of the viewport or something.

Comment: @Misherwood Maybe I'll should find another type of widget for something like that? I'm using bootstrap, and I need put some info in a static box that could be minimized.

Comment: You haven't explained what you mean by minimized. Several of us asked you.

Comment: Maybe do you want to have collapse component? http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: @isherwood Mminimize it like a window box or collapse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
$(".modal-header").click(function(){
    $(".modal-body").slideToggle();
  });
```

Could help you.. 
if you want a button for that, only change .modal-header for the button id:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    $(".modal-body").slideToggle();
  });
```